How can I delete the partition and merge it into one?
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Reena                   120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Reena                  +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 52AEFADA-23DE-48E6-A354-2133B21ED6AB
                                 Unencrypted

I'm unable to see disk1 in Disk Utility or while booting up. I want to delete disk1 and merge it with disk0.
I tried
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ eDrive /dev/disk1

but it shows the following error
You cannot erase the boot disk

Please help.

This would appear to be the precursor to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/472178/how-can-i-merge-the-two-121gb-partitions-into-a-single-one-using-the-terminal
