How can I merge the two 121GB partitions into a single one using the terminal?

I want to merge disk0s2 and disk2 into a single one using the terminal. How can I do that? I am trying to install a new OS. Can you help?

@DavidAnderson: My bad. I want to merge disk0s2 and disk2. How can I do that?

disk0 [or more specifically disk0s2] & disk2 are one and the same physical drive. They're just different representations of the same thing.

Subhadeep Mondal: I updated your question. If I am in error, then you should edit the question and make corrections.

Apple offers a guide: Use macOS Recovery on an Intel-based Mac. In your case, I think sections Start up your Intel-based Mac in macOS Recovery and Erase and reinstall macOS would offer the most help. Note that this guide by Apple does not use the diskutil command. You should not need to use the diskutil command to install macOS. In your case, I believe the output from diskutil list is just confusing you.

I would suggest first getting macOS installed. Afterwards, you can post the output from diskutil list here at Ask Different and ask questions about what is being shown.
